# Second order active low pass filter values

Tags: filter

I want to use a second order active low pass filter to cut off frequencies over 33kHz . The input is 1.3 Volts peak to peak sine wave of 32 Khz and I want to make it 30kHz of 1Vpp . The formulas for calculating the values on the components of S.O.A.L.P. are for different SOALP than mine . Can someone provide me with the formulas that I need to calculate the values of my schematic or better provide the values and explain

Edit: the op amp is provided 20V in the [+] wire and is grounded on the [-] wire

Edit 2: the formulas I found for other SOALP are on this link 
http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/filter/second-order-filters.html

[image]

Comment: Are you sure this schematic you have given will work as a Second order low pass filter ?

Comment: @MITURAJ yes I was given a variety and I chose this one

Comment: p.s. did you want gain to be 1/1.2? at 30kHz?

Comment: @MITURAJ that is actually a classic second-order Sallen-Key LPF

Comment: You cannot put AC at 0Vdc input with (V-)=0V then output will rectify. You must move up with offset or use bipolar supply

Comment: Never seen this before. Ha thanks for the reference ! @altai

Comment: found something here http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/OPseikiLowkeisan.htm @Maverick98

Comment: @MITURAJ oh this will help a lot with the calculations thank you

Comment: @MITURAJ great ref. used it too many times !

Comment: okawa tool is good for different  ways to analyze 2nd order filter, but ti.com tool is far better with more options, better methods and tolerance options. Okawa tool is better for realization of Zf/Zin with R1R2C1C2 for both Zf & Zin for lag lead servo filter but not here for LPF. The real problem is your question is as clear as mud.  33k? 32k? 30k?

Comment: No linear filter will convert a 33 kHz input signal to a 30 kHz output signal.

Comment: typo error?   input 32 kHz 1.2V, output 30kHz of 1Vpp .  Use my answer to define passband attenuation (gain) -3dB breakpoint   ( 70.7% of input)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are better steps to design a filter of this type;

Define specs then choose the type of knee response..  Low Q like Bessel give flat group delay or rate of change of phase shift.  Higher Q with steeper  edge like Chebychev compromise group delay but steeper edge and some ripple in passband. Others include Butterworth, etc.

### Filter specs

1. Choose Type & order (2, 4, 6, 8 ...) (low cost and much better performance)
   or choose characteristics  ( better)

   - Pass band gain
   - Pass Band bandwidth -3dB f
   - Pass Band Ripple
   - Reject Band __ dB at f
   - then use www.ti.com active filter tool to design AC part , then do more to correct DC bias part.
   - it only takes minutes to create an email login, validate, then use the tool http://www.ti.com/design-tools/signal-chain-design/webench-filters.html
2. Ensure DC bias is in valid CM range by adding biasing, e.g. Vcc/2 instead of Gnd.
3. Scale R up and C down to minimize current
4. Check input bias current offset voltage and balance both input R equiv with suitable R's. on (+) input.